# Using regex in python to get episode numbers from file name

Tags: python, regex

I have collected a large number of TV series on media server over the years. I wrote a script to go through and rename them all with a proper filename scheme, but I am having some trouble with the regex when trying to target multiple naming schemes.

This is my current function, which works well for getting the episode number from filenames with the scheme "s01e01"

```
def getEpisode(filename):
    matches = re.findall(r"e[0-9][0-9]", filename)
    if len(matches) == 1:
        episode = matches[0]
        episode = stripEp(episode)
        return episode  
    else:
        return False

def stripEp(target):
    target = target.strip()
    target = target.strip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.')
    return target
```

What I need to do is grab the episode number from a filename when multiple schemes are being used. I spent a while googling and tried the following.

```
matches = re.findall(r"(e[0-9][0-9]|E[0-9][0-9]|x[0-9][0-9]|X[0-9][0-9]|episode [0-9][0-9]|Episode [0-9][0-9]|\n[0-9][0-9])", filename)
```

This works in regex testers such as [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) and Python [Regex Tool](http://www.pythonregex.com/)

When I plug it into my function however, it doesn't work. This has me stumped since it seems to work in the python regex tool I linked to above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here are some examples of the schemes the files use.

```
Series Name s01e01.avi

Series Name 1x01.avi

Series Name episode 01.avi

01 Episode Title.avi
```

Comment: Doesn't work meaning it fails with some kind of exception or just doesn't find the matches you need?

Comment: I'll look into the rest of your question. but you can replace the `[0-9]` with `\d`, which looks for a digit.

Comment: And what are your multiple schemes.?Give us some examples to work with.

Comment: also, try passing the expected input through getEpisode, without the stripEp, and see if it returns the expected output. Then, also test the stripEp function. This way, you know whe"re it goes wrong, and the ammount of code you need to debug gets smaller.

Comment: Just tested the regexp part and that's fine on my machine. Has to be something else.

Comment: @Bogdan It just doesn't find the matches, the matches list is empty.

Comment: @RanRag Edited into the main post.

Comment: You might want to check out the way the folks at xbmc do it: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Advancedsettings.xml#.3Ctvshowmatching.3E

Comment: @RanRag I'll edit them into the main post, it doesn't seem you can do new line in the comments.

Comment: @Lattyware Interesting, it seems they use multiple patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filename does not contain `'\n'`. You could use `^` to indicate the start of the string,  instead:

```
def getEpisode(filename):
    match = re.search(
        r'''(?ix)                 # Ignore case (i), and use verbose regex (x)
        (?:                       # non-grouping pattern
          e|x|episode|^           # e or x or episode or start of a line
          )                       # end non-grouping pattern 
        \s*                       # 0-or-more whitespaces
        (\d{2})                   # exactly 2 digits
        ''', filename)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)

tests = (
    'Series Name s01e01.avi',
    'Series Name 1x01.avi',
    'Series Name episode 01.avi',
    '01 Episode Title.avi'
    )
for filename in tests:
    print(getEpisode(filename))
```

yields

```
01
01
01
01
```

I removed `else: return False` since Python returns `None` if it reaches the end of a function without already returning anything. Since `None` has boolean value `False`, you can test for no match with `epsiode =  getEpisode(filename); if episode: ...`.

Comment: Thank you, it seems it was working on all files but those that start with the episode number. Using ^ has fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the clarity of the regular expression

```
re.findall(r"(?:e|x|episode|\n)(\d{2})", filename, re.I)
```

and to get the season

```
re.findall(r"(?:s|season)(\d{2})(?:e|x|episode|\n)(\d{2})", filename, re.I)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems it was the \n that was not working.